# Splitting a multiple comma based Column and querying to display in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have an #table in my sql.

Select * from #temp

```
ROWNO| STD     |   SUBJECT   |   STDID
-----+---------+-------------+----------
1    FIFTHGRADE  ENGLISH,BIO     19.23452.52.62464.54
2    SIXTHGRADE  GEO,BIO         19.23452.52.62464.84
```

I'm using STRING_SPLIT to SPLIT the , from my SUBJECT

```
select STD,value as SUB,STDID
from #temp
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (SUBJECT, ',')
```

**The Result will be**

[image]

But i want my result to be displayed as the below

[image]

Where **1** represent the **STD** Value and **2** represent the **SUBJECT** Value

How can i query this ?

Thanks in advance,Jayendran

Comment: please share test data as DML

Comment: I already provided in my question Which i tried 
select STD,value as SUB,STDID
from #temp
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (SUBJECT, ',')

Comment: images are blocked in some domains,so its good to share test data ,expected,actual results  as dml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `cross apply (values ...)` to unpivot your data prior to splitting:

```
select 
    stdid
  , s.value
  , case when s.value = t.std then 1 else 2 end as i
from #temp t
  cross apply (values (t.std),(t.subject)) v(value)
  cross apply string_split(v.value, ',') s
```

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=002bc915fe98e1622ac2b401815907a6

returns:

```
+----------------------+------------+---+
|        stdid         |   value    | i |
+----------------------+------------+---+
| 19.23452.52.62464.54 | FIFTHGRADE | 1 |
| 19.23452.52.62464.54 | ENGLISH    | 2 |
| 19.23452.52.62464.54 | BIO        | 2 |
| 19.23452.52.62464.84 | SIXTHGRADE | 1 |
| 19.23452.52.62464.84 | GEO        | 2 |
| 19.23452.52.62464.84 | BIO        | 2 |
+----------------------+------------+---+
```

---

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
select 
    stdid
  , s.Item
  , case when s.Item = t.std then 1 else 2 end as i
from temp t
  cross apply (values (t.std),(t.subject)) v(value)
  cross apply delimitedsplit8K(v.value, ',') s
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MBOMG20846

---

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Comment: Is there is any other way to implement this without using String_split.Since it was introduced from SQL Server 2016

Comment: @JayendranRosh Updated with a pre-2016 version using a csv splitter tvf by Jeff Moden

Comment: Wow that was really quick thanks +1 for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all`:

```
select tt.*
from ((select t.STDID, ss.val, 2 as which
       from #temp t cross apply
            string_split(t.subject, ',') ss(val)
      ) union all
      (select t.STDID, t.STD, 1
       from #temp t
      )
     ) tt
order by STDID, which;
```